# Unable to connect Bamboo to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, bamboo

I am trying to configure Bamboo with a SQL Server Express database using JDBC however, every time I try the system attempts it then returns me to the set-up screen (see below). Password, Username and database name are correct and SQL Server Express is running (according to system services). Possible relevant log lines are at the bottom.

Server name is `LT-N0099\SQLEXPRESS`.

I think the URL is the issue, I've tried:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=bamboo
jdbc:sqlserver://LT-N0099\SQLEXPRESS; databaseName=bamboo
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=bamboo
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS; databaseName=bamboo
```

Please let me know if this isn't an appropriate venue to ask this question. Thank you!

Access log:

```
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:10:51:19 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 12497 1074 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:25 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:25 -0400] "GET /bootstrap/selectSetupStep.action HTTP/1.1" 302 - 7 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:26 -0400] "GET /setup/setupDatabase.action HTTP/1.1" 200 9504 659 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:26 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 6224 42178 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:31 -0400] "POST /setup/chooseDatabaseType.action HTTP/1.1" 302 - 10 "http://localhost:8085/setup/setupDatabase.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:31 -0400] "GET /setup/setupDatabaseConnection.action?selectedDatabase=mssql HTTP/1.1" 200 12251 682 "http://localhost:8085/setup/setupDatabase.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:09:56 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 12245 759 "http://localhost:8085/setup/setupDatabaseConnection.action?selectedDatabase=mssql" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:10:05 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 6224 2915 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:10:07 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 19 9 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:10:09 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 19 6 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
"-" 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [23/May/2022:11:10:11 -0400] "POST /setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action HTTP/1.1" 200 19 3 "http://localhost:8085/setup/performSetupDatabaseConnection.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable TCP/IP  and set the instance to listen on port 1433 in SQL Server Configuration Manager? By default SQL Server Express Edition has TCP/IP disabled, and listens on a dynamic port when it is.  Even then to connect from a remote host you need to create a Windows Firewall exclusion.

Comment: I have, no luck.